How to access the content of dynamically created tabs using Tab Control in WPF
this is my first time asking a question so I'll try to add as much detail as possible. Also please note that I'm not an incredibly experienced programmer so anything not too complicated would be nice (unless you have a definite solution, in that case I'll try my best).
In my project, I'm dynamically opening and closing tabs using a tab control. The thing that determines the content of each tab is a DataTemplate in TabControl.Resources. The TabControl itself has its ItemsSource binded to an ObservableCollection where, each time I add a new tab, the UI is updated to the relevant tab type and its correct content.
I have kept in only what I think is relevant to the code below:

<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    <TabControl.Resources>            
        <!--To make a new team tab-->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CreateTeamTab" DataType="TabItem">
            <Grid>
                <!--Grid row and columns definitions blah blah blah-->

                    <!--This is the main TextBox that I would like to access. But overall I just want to know how to access all the content of this tab so that I can then access whatever I want.-->
                    <TextBox Name="TeamIdTextbox"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>  

This is the C# code for the project:
    //Observable Collection to store the dynamically created tabs
    ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        tabControl.DataContext = tabs;
        CreateTeamTab();
        AccessContent();
    }
    private void CreateTeamTab()
    {
        //creates a new tabitem that i can populate with the data that i need
        TabItem tb = new TabItem();

        //creates the header
        tb.Header = "Create Team";

        //places the contents from the Tabcontrol.resources into the content of the tab.
        tb.ContentTemplate = tabControl.FindResource("CreateTeamTab") as DataTemplate;
        
        //adds the tab to the Observable Collection
        tabs.Add(tb);
        tabControl.SelectedItem = tb;
    }

    public void AccessContent()
    {
        //Down here I want to be able to access the content of the tab I just created (or any tab in the tabControl for that matter)
        //And if it helps, I'd specifically like to access the TeamIdTextbox from the tab I just created
    }

Because I'm not very experienced, I'm not sure whether I've tried these correctly.
I've tried:
TabItem currentTab = (TabItem)tabControl.SelectedItem;
TextBox textbox = (TextBox)currentTab.FindName("TeamIdTextbox");

For above, I've replaced the TabItem type with DataTemplate, UserControl and FrameworkElement. I don't think it works for any of them (usually the textbox is null).
I also tried getting the content using currentTab.Content
I will say, one thing that DID work was: in one of the events, i had a Button passed in as the sender and i did this to access the item I needed:
Button button = (Button)sender;

//gets the parent of the button
DockPanel dockPanel = (DockPanel)button.Parent;

//gets the parent of the dockpanel
Grid grid = (Grid)dockPanel.Parent;

//Finds the textbox
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)grid.FindName("PNameTextbox");

However, whilst this did work, it doesn't work in the method above because I'm not passing in any UI as a sender. Plus, it would be easier overall if I could just access the content of the tab I need.
Finally, one thing I haven't tried yet is using binding for the textbox. However, for reasons that would take a bit too long to explain, I would prefer not to use binding, so anything else would be nice.
Hopefully I have provided a detailed enough description. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

You do not create tabs in code-behind.  They will be created for you.  The TabControl is an ItemsControl.  That means that when you bind it to an ObservableCollection as you've done, it creates a tab for each item in the collection for you, automatically and uses the DataTemplate you've specified.  The is the job of ItemsControl, to do that you don't have to.  Not only TabControl but all the classes derived from ItemsControl (e.g. ListBox,  ComboBox, etc).  As long as the type of the DataTemplate matches the type that the ObservableCollection contains, you should be good

So your only job is is to make sure that the DataTemplate shows what you want by binding to the specific properties of the items in the bound collection.  And if each item in the bound collection is different, all you need to do is write a separate default DataTemplate for each item type and place it in the Resources section of the TabControl itself.  The TabControl will then use it to create the UI

Part of the problem is: the tabcontrol content (visual tree) is only loaded for the currently selected tab, it doesn't necessarily exist for the background tabs. So any tab in the tabControl is not available to you -> you should find a different approach to solve your actual problem. Generally speaking: if you want to work with the UI, you should only care about the currently displayed tab (that might be possible) but if you want to work with the data, you should manage them outside of their visual representation (e.g. viewmodel, with binding to the view)
